# xCode "Send Backward" Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know if there's a keyboard shortcut for sending an object backward in the interface builder?

If the answer is no, is there a way to create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to XCode Preferences- Key Bindins and assign your shortcut

[image]

Comment: Brilliant thank you! However I couldn't make the changes there so I made them in the System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shotcuts